# Why is AWS SES' create-custom-verification-email-template returning a BadRequestException?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When running the following command:

```
aws sesv2 create-custom-verification-email-template --cli-input-json file://template.json --profile my-profile --region us-west-2
```

...I get the following response:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateCustomVerificationEmailTemplate operation:
```

Note that there is no clarification given at the end of the error message. (The colon implies that there should be additional information, but none is present)

(For brevity, I'm omitting test cases since I've already solved the problem - see the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the problem was that the HTML template I was using contained HTML comments.

**Removing the HTML comments results in successful template creation.**

When I use a simplified test case with something like the following, I receive the error.

```
{
    "TemplateName": "...",
    "FromEmailAddress": "...",
    "TemplateSubject": "...",
    "TemplateContent": "<html><body><!-- comment --></body></html>",
    "SuccessRedirectionURL": "...",
    "FailureRedirectionURL": "..."
}
```

If I use something like the following instead, the template is successfully created.

```
{
    "TemplateName": "...",
    "FromEmailAddress": "...",
    "TemplateSubject": "...",
    "TemplateContent": "<html><body></body></html>",
    "SuccessRedirectionURL": "...",
    "FailureRedirectionURL": "..."
}
```